# Where are the po files and how to translate strings without using the UI?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm using Drupal 8 built-in translation. I've English and Spanish in my website. I've translated the website to Spanish as well. But I don't see any po files for the translation script. I've checked it under `sites/default/files/`.

Also I've to translate a lot of strings to Spanish, How do I do that using po files without using the UI interface for the translation.